# From Luton Airport to Hammersmith by taxi or Uber

Tags: airport-transfer, london, taxis, uber, ltn

I need to travel together with four more people (three adults at two children in total with me) from Luton Airport to Hammersmith on early Sunday morning (approx. 8 a.m.) and return on early Friday evening (approx. 6 p.m.).

I have reviewed my coach / train options ([here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35509/15281), [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35095/15281) and [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109627/15281) + Wikitravel) and found:

- the total trip fee to be between 100 GBP to 190 GB for five people, two ways and
- travelling time taking between 1,5 hour to 2,5 hour one way.

I'd like to consider taxi or Uber (always for five people, so rather a large car option).

Can someone share an approx. cost and travel time in this case? Or advice any webpage or service where I can check this myself?

Comment: The Uber app will give you an estimate directly, although their pricing model can mean that it's out of date when you come to book. Any local taxi company will give you a price for the job. Just phone them and ask. Google is a good place to find them.

Comment: I've usually used minicabit (I'm not an affiliate) for airport transfers with taxis when I had lots of luggage or 3-4 people, they give an online estimate too.

Comment: As @SgrA mentioned use minicabit. You will get your price options and you can get a price depending on the luggage you have. And you don't have a train station at Luton airport. You have to take the connecting bus to Luton Airport Parkway (10 mins) which is the train station serving Luton airport